# looking for these spring security message names to customize them

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, ldap

I have an application that uses ldap (bind authenticator) for login. I need to find the particular keys for these messages thrown by SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message in order to "customize" them. I already got the "Bad Credentials" one done using `BindAuthenticator.badCredentials`, just need the rest.

1. Empty Password
2. Empty Username
3. Customer not found with specified username

That last one is weird, could it be thrown by the ldap server itself?

Another thing I'm not getting is the label of another localization/language. All my spring message files work out in my application except the error ones at login. I have two property files:

1. spring-security-messages_en_US.properties
2. spring-security-messages_es_ES.properties

It's pulling all my messages regardless of loc/language from the en_US property file. The code on my Jsp is the following:

```
<c:if test="${param.error==true}">
    <div class="error">
         <c:out value="${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message}"/>
    </div>
</c:if>
```

Not sure if I have to use the `<spring:message>` tag here or it won't use the other property file. I tried using it but unsure on how to pass the exception to it.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could it happen that messages as "Empty Password" come from validation instead spring security?

Comment: I have no idea here. I'm sort of new to this. Is there anyway to catch these messages and customize them?

Comment: I looked for in spring security messages for those ones and I did not find them, that is what I was wondering where they come from.

Answer (score 0):

LDAP clients should use the LDAP operation code (an integer) that is contained in the response transmitted from the server. The message text can be customized per server and per API.

The result codes are standardized and listed at the [result code section of the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4511#appendix-A).

Comment: is there a way I could see which operation code refers to which of my messages listed? I'm confused on how to use this information to implement customization. Most of the messages are general situations and do not specify like the 3 I have listed.